# Are nodes in a linked list separate structs or part of the same struct?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, sizeof, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list in C as follows:

```
typedef struct intSet *link;

typedef struct intSet {
    int num;
    link next;
} intSet;
```

When I printed the size of the various members of the struct, I got the following:

```
sizeof(List) = 8 bytes  //List is a newly created list
sizeof(curr->num) = 4 bytes  // curr is just a node within the list
sizeof(curr->next) = 8 bytes
```

My question is: does the struct itself always have a size of 8 bytes regardless of how many elements we have in the list, or are those 8 bytes only pertaining to the first node and that the next nodes in the list are different instances of the same struct?

The reason I'm asking is that because I'm planning to implement this as a user-defined data type in PostgreSQL and as such it requires me to declare whether the length of the data type is constant or variable:

```
CREATE TYPE list (
    internallength = 8? or internallength = variable
    input = ..., output = ... );
```

If it is variable I have to change my struct representation to:

```
typedef struct intSet {
    int size;
    int num;
    link next;
} intSet;
```

and I suspect I might have to update the size constantly if the nodes are separate and not different parts of the same struct as the next node may have a size of 4 bytes more than the last node.
Any tips or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `does the struct itself always have a size of 8 bytes regardless of how many elements we have in the list` a struct's size doesn't change at runtime, but I doubt its 8 bytes, it should be 16 bytes. I assume `List` is a pointer, so you got the size of a pointer, not the size of the struct.

Comment: Never ever `typedef` a (data) pointer. Oh, and you should read about pointers in your preferred C textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concern about sizeof is not the main issue especially that in 32 bits sizeof(intSet) will be 8 and in 64 bits the sizeof(intSet) will be 32 bits.

Concerning PostgreSQL, the object you want to store is an `int` container and therefore of variable length. Therefore the object you want to handle is not intSet but a struct containing the size and the first element of your list.

```
typedef struct intSet *link;

typedef struct intSet {
    int num;
    link next;
};

struct intSetSized
{
    int size;
    intSet begin;
};
```

It is `intSetSized`  that you want to declare as your User-defined Types as in [udt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xtypes.html).

And each you add or remove something from your list you adjust `size`.

Be careful on how you implement  input and output functions for your object `intSetSized` it is more tricky that the example given in [udt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xtypes.html).

Comment: In my task, I'm retrieving the 'set' as a string, so now I'm thinking of storing it as a string within the struct instead of as a linked list within the struct like above which is a lot more complicated. I'm thinking of creating a linked list from this 'set' (e.g. "{1, 2, 3}"), so in such cases I can palloc the string then use malloc afterwards when I create the list for operations right?

Comment: From what I gather in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xtypes.html you need to serialize your object as a string (converting to char *) and deserialize from a string. Whether you do the conversion from string to `int set` inside the I/O functions or outside is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your type `link` is a pointer, as would be more evident if you didn't obfuscate it with the `typedef`. The thing pointed to is a separate `struct` (which also has its own `next` point, etc), which needs its own storage.

Now `sizeof(curr->next)` and `sizeof(List)` are the size of the *pointer to struct*, not the size of `struct intSet`. `sizeof(*(curr->next))` and `sizeof(struct intSet)` would both be the size of the struct itself, i.e., the amount of space you need to allocate for a *single* struct.

Never does `sizeof` traverse the pointers to find out the size of the entire list. If you need to find out the entire size of the list, you need to traverse it yourself and count the elements, then the total size is `count * sizeof(struct intSet)`. It is unlikely that you should need this information for a linked list, though, since if you allocate the entire list at once you could just use an array without the `next` links…

Comment: Also note that you cannot store the `next` (or any other) pointers in the database, since they are only valid for those specific allocations.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` for the pointer is same in a system. In your case it is always going to be 4 bytes irrespective of what it is pointing to (be it int, char, struct etc). It is going to be 4 bytes in your case.
Hence your struct size will be 8 bytes always (4 bytes for int + 4 bytes for pointer).